# TabBar visibility issue after window root change

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiwindow

After entering to the foreground I am performing a request, during which I am changing the root view controller of the main window to a fake launch screen like view controller, temporarily keeping the current root(which is tab bar controller with nested nav controllers), after performing the request, based on the response I am swapping the root back with the temporarily saved "old" root view controller(the tabor controller)

after the swapping with the old root, the tabor shows up in inner pages where hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is set to true, tabor disappears correctly after any push or pop  transitions

I have already refactored this bit to a simpler and smarter one, but my question still exists, what happens? and why does tab bar show up on a VC with hidesBottomBarWhenPushed set after root swap

Here is some of that code:

```
private func animateRootChange(to viewController: UIViewController, _ completion: ((_ completed: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    guard let window = window else { return }
    
    window.rootViewController = viewController
    
    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil) { (completed) in
        completion?(completed)
    }
}


func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    guard let window = window,
          let currentRoot = window.rootViewController else {
        return
    }
            
    animateRootChange(to: LaunchScreenViewController(), nil)
    
    TheRequestWithFunctionCall { [weak self] (model: ForceUpdate) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        aBoolean ? self.animateRootChange(to: currentRoot, nil) : self.animateRootChange(to: LogInViewController(), nil)

    } failure: { [weak self] (_) in
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the rootViewController this way, I do honestly think it would be easier to either :

- If it is a simple 'fake launch screen', simply present a view controller over the current top view controller.
- Use a tab controller with hidden tabs, and switch between these two tabs. That's good way to switch an app between two states like 'logged' and 'not logged' for example.

I'm quite sure you will have no problem with one of these options. Changing the root controller 'the hard way' seems hazardous to me.

Comment: yes I have refactored already this code and just presented the "Launch screen", even before posting the issue, but my question still remains, why this happens

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't know then.. Surely due to the way the view/viewController hierarchy ( nearest tab / nav ancestors  ) is managed internally. Have you tried to call 'rootViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)' before doing the transition and 'didMove' after?

I let my answer anyway for those who would like to know the alternative.